# Runtime error with QTcpSocket and slots and signals

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I am writing some code to establish a TCP socket and I am getting an error trying to setup the signals that I am trying to listen to.

The code is:

```
connection = new QTcpSocket(this);

connect(connection,SLOT(connected()),this,SIGNAL(onConnection()));
connect(connection,SLOT(readyRead()),this,SIGNAL(gotData()));
connect(connection,SLOT(disconnected()),this,SIGNAL(onConnection()));
```

The Error that I am getting is:

```
 Object::connect: Attempt to bind non-signal QTcpSocket::connected()
 Object::connect: Attempt to bind non-signal QTcpSocket::readyRead()
 Object::connect: Attempt to bind non-signal QTcpSocket::disconnected()
```

I can't find anyone else that is having the same problem. I am thinking that it is just something silly that I am doing. My other signals in this program are working.

Comment: The syntax is connect( sender, receiver ), not vice versa. Signal comes first, then slot (or other signal).

Answer (score 6):

You are using QObject::connect method in bad way!

you must use connect method like this:

```
connection = new QTcpSocket(this);

connect(connection,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(onConnection()));
connect(connection,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(gotData()));
connect(connection,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(onConnection()));
```

and for more information go [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Understanding_Signals_and_Slot_in_Qt).

Comment: QObject::connect is not reason of this problem